# Jenkins Pipeline Interdependent Parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm fairly new to Jenkins Pipeline (and Groovy), and am wondering if it's possible to define parameters in a way that one depends on another based on the selected value. For example let's say I have two choice parameters, A and B, and I want choices in B to be populated based on the [dynamically] selected value of A. Is that possible? Something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'my-agent' }

    parameters {
        choice(name: 'DataCenter', choices:'Foo\nBar')
        choice(name: 'AvailabilityZone', choices: if(DataCenter.equals("Foo") {return 'A\nB'} else {return 'C\nD'}))
    }

    stages {
    ...
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work. Is there way to support this out of the box? Otherwise is there a way to, let's say, bind a callback event to the `DataCenter` choice dropdown and manually change the values of `AvailabilityZone`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need in the past and solved it using the [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin).

Unfortunately, this plugin was [recently blacklisted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/biouno-users/p3ZfSTPIOQs) due to a security issue in one of its dependencies.

If security is not a major concern, you can still [install the plugin manually](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/biouno-users/Y7RfkOvizZ8).

Comment: This plugin doesn't support Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: It does support the now-called "scripted" pipelines (this plugin works with 4 pipeline jobs in my environment). Looking at your code again, I now understand you're working with "declarative" pipelines, which will probably not work with such plugins.